# DateAdd insert in a column without timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has a date column(Type - DateTime), I am inserting 
`DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())` into 100 rows, each row is updated with correct date and common timestamp, however when I select the table as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE date = CONVERT(DATE, '2018-08-16 17:06:55:450'
```

Nothing is being returned, although I can see this is the date value inserted.

Also, how do I insert just the date and leave timestamp to 0?

Comment: MySql or MSSQL?

Comment: MSSQL mate......

Comment: That's because of ` CONVERT(DATE, '2018-08-16 17:06:55:450'` since you've included the time, you should change the convert to DATETIME and not DATE.

Comment: It worked after setting DATEFORMAT ydm;

Comment: `CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-08-16 17:06:55')` OR you can just do `[date] = '2018-08-16'`

Comment: Also, converting DATETIME to DATE will leave the timestamp as zeros. so this `CONVERT(DATE, '2018-08-16 17:06:55')` would return this `2018-08-16 00:00:00`

Comment: t worked after setting DATEFORMAT ydm;

Comment: How do I insert date without time stamp, any idea pls

Comment: just change the column from datetime to date. If you're selecting records from a table and you want to insert them into another, you could cast the datetime to date, like this `SELECT CAST([datetimecolumn] AS DATE) ` this would insert the date part only, leaving the time part out.

Comment: We cant change the column type, can we do something like '2018-08-16 00:00:00:000' with DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())

Answer (score 0):

Also, how do I insert just the date and leave timestamp to 0?

You just need to convert getdate() to a date and it will strip the timestamp.
DATEADD(DAY, -1, convert( date,GETDATE()) )